# why JQuery ui tabs not working using html

Tags: jquery

I have jquery tab code I want to run on my system. What are the prerequisites for JQuery to run?

The steps I followed are

1. copied jQuery tabs code in notepad++
2. Saved as test.html

tried to run but it's not working. What might be the problem?

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You did not explicitly state what "not working" means.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console when running it in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have no-prefix (scheme is not defined) in url, browser requests link with base url's scheme component, so if page not opened from a server, base scheme will be file and browser will request for `file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css` and could not load that file.

change

```
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
```

with

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
```

Comment: Please explain why this is a potential fix for running the script from a non-server url.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is going to be you don't have the CSS files it's referencing for styling. I recommend deleting the lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

and see about making your own CSS files to style the tabs and text. Without the styling it will still switch the content when you select the tab hyperlinks, it will just be very ugly.

Comment: Thanks I removed the css and added my own css and it's working